# why is php complaining about passing by reference in this code?

Tags: php

```
$test = 'love';
$eff = end(explode('ov',$test));
```

I can't figure it out; oddly enough, this doesn't get a complain:

```
$test = 'love';
$eff = current(explode('ov',$test));
```

The error I'm getting is:
Strict: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you're expecting end() to give you the last element in the array, you're misunderstanding the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`end()` modifies the array passed to it, by reference. Assign the explosion to a variable first so that `end()` has a reference it can modify.

```
$test = 'love';
$explosion = explode('ov',$test);
$eff = end($explosion);
```

`end()` only changes an internal pointer so it doesn't modify the contents of the array in anyway and you won't notice unless you're using the `current()`, `each()`, `next()` lot for iteration.

If this limitation of `end()` is annoying to you there are ways around it:

```
function last($array) { return end($array); }
$test = 'love';
$eff = last(explode('ov', $test));
```

Answer (score 5):

`end` changes the array's internal pointer by moving it to the end of the array.  Thus, the parameter must be mutable (that is, a reference to an array) for that operation to be useful.  This is why you receive the warning.

`current` doesn't touch the array at all; it only looks at the array.  Thus, the parameter does not need to be mutable (thus can be passed by value) and the operation doesn't give you a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The `explode` returns a temporary array, which you are not 'storing' to a variable but rather passing directly to `end` which expects a reference.

I believe the reason why `current` does not trigger the error is that it is non-mutating.  Other mutating functions such as `array_unshift` and `reset` complain too.

Comment: `current` expects reference as well. that's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT);

$test = 'love';
$eff = end(explode('ov',$test));
var_dump($eff);

?>
```

it will work fine if your error reporting level is not set to `E_STRICT`.

See, when you have an temporary array returned, you cannot just set the internal pointer just like this. You need to set it to a variable first then move the internal pointer to the end using `end()`.

This is true so for: `reset()`, `next()`, `prev()` and so on.

The following would work instead.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT);

$test = 'love';
$a = explode('ov',$test);
$eff = end($a);
var_dump($eff);

?>
```

`current()` works because it does not move the internal pointer, but to get what the current element that the internal pointer is pointing at.

Comment: You'll get the errors when you use ``error_reporting(E_STRICT)`` in PHP 5.x, too.  E_STRICT is only a subset of E_ALL under PHP 6.x.

Comment: Whether `E_STRICT` is a subset of `E_ALL` varies quite a bit depending on PHP version, I think. It wasn't and then it was and then it wasn't again. But you never want to set `error_reporting` to `E_STRICT` alone. You want to OR it together with `E_ALL` (`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`), otherwise you're going to miss important non-strict errors. If `E_STRICT` is contained in `E_ALL` it won't do any harm to OR it in anyway.